# Was the Quran always written with diacritics?

Tags: quran, arabic

Arabic writing can be also understood without [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics). Was the Quran ever written without diacritics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oldest manuscripts of the Qur'an are only very sparsely pointed, like this one:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Folio_Blue_Quran_Met_2004.88.jpg

If they do have vowels, these are indicated by red dots above or below the letters, not with the later standard vowel signs, like this one:

http://www.islamic-awareness.org/Quran/Text/Mss/tubingen.html

(The second of these has some "modern" vowel signs added later in black ink.)